# Making a simple clickable list in Android X using Kotlin and SQLite (Android Studio 4.1)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm coming from Android Java and I've used `ListView` earlier. Now I'm trying to create a simple list in Android X Kotlin using `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.

My app is working, but I'm unsure how to implement the onclick listener for items.

My app have the following:

- DatabaseHelper : Creates a table "categories" and inserts some categories
- IdTitleDataClass : Data class for categories, has fields id and title
- IdTitleAdapter : The List adapter. It uses layout "adapter_id_title_item_layout"
- adapter_id_title_item_layout : Layout for list items
- activity_main : Layout for activity main with one "androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"
- MainActivity : Gets data from table and shows it into list.

Source code is located here:
https://github.com/europa9/KotlinAndroidXRecycleViewSimpleSQLite

[image]

### UPDATED CODE 26.10.2020

**DatabaseHelper**

```
package net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.db

import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.DatabaseUtils
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper


class DatabaseHelper(context: Context):
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSIOM) {


    companion object {
        private val DB_NAME = "kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite"
        private val DB_VERSIOM = 1;
    }


    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        val q1 = "CREATE TABLE categories" +
                "(category_id Integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "category_name TEXT)"
        db?.execSQL(q1)

        val q2 = "INSERT INTO categories(category_id, category_name) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "(NULL, 'Bread and cereal')," +
                "(NULL, 'Bread')," +
                "(NULL, 'Cereals')," +
                "(NULL, 'Frozen bread and rolls')," +
                "(NULL, 'Crispbread')," +
                "(NULL, 'Sausage bread and lumps')," +
                "(NULL, 'Dessert and baking')," +
                "(NULL, 'Baking')," +
                "(NULL, 'Biscuit')," +
                "(NULL, 'Cakes')," +
                "(NULL, 'Buns')"
        db?.execSQL(q2)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categories")

        onCreate(db)

    }

    // Query database - insert or update
    fun query(query: String): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        db.execSQL(query)
        db.close()
        return true;
    } // query

    // Count
    fun count(query: String): Int {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val numRows =
            DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, query, null).toInt()
        db.close()
        return numRows;
    }

    // Get
    fun rawQuery(query: String?): Cursor? {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val mCursor: Cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)
        mCursor?.moveToFirst()
        return mCursor
    }


}
```

**IdTitleAdapter**

```
package net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.recyclerViewAdapters

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.adapter_id_title_item_layout.view.*

class IdTitleAdapter(val list: ArrayList<IdTitleDataClass>,val clickLambda: (Int)->Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<IdTitleViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IdTitleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_id_title_item_layout,parent,false)
        return IdTitleViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IdTitleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = list[position]
        holder.textViewTitle.text = currentItem.title
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickLambda(currentItem.id)
        }
    }

} // IdTitleAdapter

class IdTitleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val textViewTitle: TextView = itemView.textViewTitle

} // IdTitleViewHolder
```

**IdTitleDataClass**

```
package net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.recyclerViewAdapters


data class IdTitleDataClass (val id:Int, val title:String)
```

**MainActivity**

```
package net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite

/**
 *
 * File: MainActivity.kt
 * Version 1.0
 * Date 24.10.2020
 * Copyright (c) 2020 S Ditlefsen
 * License: http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 *
 */

import android.database.Cursor
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.db.DatabaseHelper
import net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.recyclerViewAdapters.IdTitleAdapter
import net.frindex.kotlinandroidxrecycleviewsimplesqlite.recyclerViewAdapters.IdTitleDataClass
import java.util.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Class variables
    var db: DatabaseHelper? = null
    private lateinit var categoriesList: ArrayList<IdTitleDataClass>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // DB :: Open Chrome and go to URL chrome://inspect/#devices
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)

        // List categories
        listCategories()


    } // onCreate

    /*- List categories -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    fun listCategories(){

        // DB
        db = DatabaseHelper(this)

        // Fetch categories
        var categoriesCursor: Cursor? = db!!.rawQuery("SELECT category_id, category_name FROM categories")
        var categoriesSize: Int = categoriesCursor!!.count
        Log.d("listCategories()", "categoriesSize=" + categoriesSize)

        // Add a list of categories
        categoriesList = ArrayList<IdTitleDataClass>()
        while (categoriesCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val categoryId = categoriesCursor.getInt(0)
            val categoryName = categoriesCursor.getString(1)
            Log.d("listCategories()", "categoryId=" + categoryId + " categoryName=" + categoryName)
            categoriesList.add(IdTitleDataClass(categoryId, categoryName))

        }

        // Add to list
        recycler_view.adapter = IdTitleAdapter(categoriesList) {
            categoriesList[it]
        }
        recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)

    } // listCategories
} // MainActivity
```

> ---

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">
    
    
        <!-- Categories -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/rva_id_title_item_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <!-- //Categories -->
    
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**adapter_id_title_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Question: How should I proceed to implement onclick listener for the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes most sense to me, since you pass the list as an argument to the adapter, is passing what it should with its items as well. Of course, that's a preference, there's no right or wrong, just be sure to stay consistent with your team if you have one.

```
class IdTitleAdapter(
    val list: ArrayList<IdTitleDataClass>,
    val clickLambda: suspend (Int)->Unit)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<IdTitleViewHolder>()
```

Suspend is optional, just in case you are using coroutines and you are making a network call or something.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IdTitleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = list[position]
        holder.textViewTitle.text = currentItem.title
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickLambda(currentItem.id)
        }
    }
```

And you initialized the adapter like so:

```
recycler_view.adapter = IdTitleAdapter(categoriesList) {
    something(it)  /* or even categoriesList[it]
    if you passed the position instead of the id */
}
```

Comment: What is setOnClickListener? I get this error: Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener. Also what is something(it)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type `itemView` (fixed now). With setOnClickListener you set a click listener to the desirable view. If itemView doesn't fulfill your needs you can alternatively set id to any other view in [LinearLayout](https://github.com/europa9/KotlinAndroidXRecycleViewSimpleSQLite/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/adapter_id_title_item_layout.xml) and set the click listener on it. For example, `holder.textViewTitle.setOnClickListener { clickLambda(currentItem.id) }` if you wish for your text view to be clickable.

Comment: `something()` is not a real function, it represents a method you have to implement which will be called when your item is clicked. For example, if you change the `clickLambda` to `val clickLambda: (TextView)->Unit` and you pass the `TextView` in `onBindHolder` like so `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { clickLambda(holder.textViewTitle) }`, you can have `recycler_view.adapter = IdTitleAdapter(categoriesList) { it.text = "Hello World!" }` which will change the text of each item when you click it.

Comment: I dont understand. I get this error on clickLambda: "Suspend function 'invoke' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Comment: Just remove `suspend`. As I said it is only there in case you were going to use coroutines. The above example with coroutines could be like that: `recycler_view.adapter = IdTitleAdapter(categoriesList) { MainScope().launch { it.text = "Hello World!" } }`. Don't use it though, if you don't know what it is. When you are ready to get more confused read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) 

Comment: Ok, Thanks! When I removed suspend the app lunches. However when I click a item nothing really happens. Shouldn't a click on a list item make a function call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223601/discussion-between-rtsketo-and-europa).

Comment: `recycler_view.adapter = IdTitleAdapter(categoriesList) { /* here you do whatever you want to happen when someone clicks an item */ }`